# FragmentTransaction replace doesn't work

Tags: java, android, fragment

I won't replace my fragment, but I have one problem,
when I call `replace` after `beginTransaction()`  Android Studio doesn't give  me an error.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager 
        .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment);
```

However, when I do something like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.l, fragment);
```

Android Studio tells me that `fragmentTransaction` doesn't have this method. 
When I do something like this I am having error that `commit()` return `int` and AS proposes to transfer `fragmentTransaction` to `int`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager 
            .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: You are missing a ";" in your second statement.

Comment: The chain call `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment).commit()` doesn't return a `FragmentTransaction`. You don't need to keep the fragment transaction around after you call commit. So just remove the equal sign and everything before it.

Comment: @luiscosta its typo in my app i did its right

Comment: @Jonathan727 when i wrote  `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace().commit();` AS dont found `beginTransaction()` in fragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
> FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
> fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.l, fragment);
> ```
>
> Android Studio say me that fragmentTransaction dont have this method

In the above section you are missing `;` after `beginTransacton()` so please add that. Also make sure you have View R.id.l and fragment of type Fragment bcoz method definition is as follows `replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)` Alternatively you can use `replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`
**[For more info refer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))**

**Coming to other Question**

> ```
> FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
> FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager 
>             .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment).commit();
> ```
>
> When i do something like this i am having error that commit() return
>   int and AS proposes to transfer fragmentTransaction to int

commit is method with FragmentTransaction who's **return type is int** you can refer it's **[signature here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit())** 
So you can do

```
int commitValue = = fragmentManager 
                 .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment).commit();
```

**Also make sure you with Fragment and FragmentManager both belong to same package either are from android.app.* OR both are from android.support.v4.app.* that is support library**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first two snippets, you are missing the commit() on the transaction, so nothing is replaced.

The last one is mostly correct, just don't expect the method to return a FragmentTransaction. This should work:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.l, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: `AS dont found beginTransaction() in fragmentManager`

Comment: Ẁhich class do you import in your code, android.app.FragmentManager?

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to do:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.l, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

that's all. Hope it helps you!

Comment: @FrancescoAzzolawhen i do somesing like this

    `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();   
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.l, fragment); `  
Android Studio say me that `fragmentTransaction` dont have this method.

Comment: welll you can know what kind of method you have, are you sure you aren't use a support library and something else for fragment or vice versa? Give a look at your import statements!!